# C# Bug or Something Wrong

Tags: c#, vb.net, percentage, division

I have an issue with C# not calculating correctly for me to draw my progress bar.

```
int width = 130;
int maxValue = 20;
int value = 20;

int percent = (width / maxValue) * value
```

Now it should return 130 so it mean my progress bar is full but it returns 120 so I don't know what is happening.

here is and image of progress bar https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhYnX.jpg

I also tested the formula with VB.NET and it worked perfectly.

I am using VS2013 in Windows 7 x86.

Comment: C# bug?  For future reference...it is __never__ a bug in the C# compiler.

Comment: Always a compiler bug, never the 'programmer'.

Comment: If you don't want to start casting, you can change your formula: percent = (width * value) / maxValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`130 / 20` performs [integer divison](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html)

From [`/` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For
>   example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2

That's why it always discards the fractional part and it returns `6`. That's why your result will be `6 * 20` which is equal to `120`.

As a solution, you can change your *integer division* to *floating-point division*.

For example;

```
var percent = (130.0 / 20) * 20;
var percent = (130 / 20.0) * 20;
```

That means, you need to define one of your variable as a `double`, or cast one of them to `double` in your calculation.

Comment: It looks like every answer in this question was downvoted.  Perhaps a serial downvoter?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yeah, it smells like..

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the values to double:

```
int percent = (int)(((double)width / (double)maxValue) * (double)value);
```

`130 / 20 = 6.5` and it will be implicitely converted to `integer` which makes `6` of it. So the wrong value is used for the following multiplication

Comment: Or use doubles in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dividing two `int` variables, you're performing integer division.
130/20 is 6.5, which, in integer context is truncated to 6. It is then multiplied by 20, to generate the result of 120.

You could avoid this issue completely by defining your variables as `double`s:

```
double width = 130;
double maxValue = 20;
double value = 20;

double percent = (width / maxValue) * value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, dividing an integer by an integer always results in an integer.

If you don't want an integer result, make sure at least one of the operands is a float or double:

```
int width = 130;
float maxValue = 20.0;
int value = 20;

int percent = (width / maxValue) * value
```